# Tomcat6 ignores META-INF/context.xml

Tags: tomcat, jndi, context.xml

Tomcat6 keeps ignoring my META-INF/context.xml.  I keep getting "Name tt is not bound in this Context" when I try to look up "tt" (please see 'details').

When I put the content of META-INF/context.xml inside the 'context' tag in server.xml, it works.  I've also checked that **$Tomcat-base/Catalina/localhost is empty**, so my META-INF/context.xml is not overridden.

---

details:

Tomcat version: 6.0.10

Here's my Webroot structure:

Webroot
       |-META-INF
       |      |-context.xml
       |
       |-WEB-INF
             |-web.xml

Content of context.xml:

```
<Context>
    <Environment name="tt" value="this is a string" type="java.lang.String"></Environment>
</Context>
```

Context tag of this webroot in server.xml:

```
<Context path="/test" docBase="E:\javaProjects\TestProject\Webroot" reloadable="true"></Context>
```

The way I look up for "tt":

```
...
Context ic = new InitialContext();
Context ec = (Context) ic.lookup("java:comp/env");
String str = (String) ec.lookup("tt");
System.out.println("str is "+str);
```

The error I get:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name tt is not bound in this context
```

Comment: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=42747              I wonder if my problem is a bug as described in the link

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've got your code working **IF I delete** the `<Context>` from the server.xml and define it only in the `META-INF/context.xml`

It doesn't work when the `<Context>` is defined in both places.

Secondly, **change your type to String**, instead of Integer

```
<Environment name="tt" value="this is a string" type="java.lang.String"></Environment>
</Context>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  That Integer was a typo as I used Integer initially.  The thing is, if I delete <Context> from server.xml, then tomcat has no way to know where to locate my Webroot folder, unless I put the Webroot inside tomcat's webapps folder.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Ideally Tomcat will decipher the path from the docBase automatically, so for your path name "/test". Instead of keeping the project in `E:\javaProjects\TestProject\Webroot` it would be in `TOMCAT_HOME\webapps\test`, so then you wont need the entry in server.xml at all.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have two contexts in one host defined in two different files, that was the root of problem. For more info read [this](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) article.